# Setup Chromecast (networks and apps)

Tags: chromecast

1. Is it possible to set up a Chromecast device for different (>1) WiFi? (a backup plan)
2. Is it possible to set up a Chromecast device for different WiFi and networks? (use in different houses)
3. Is it possible to set up a Chromecast device without using the Google Home app and play? (maybe an F-Droid app)

Comment: Leaning toward off-topic as while some chromecasts use Android, they are Google made devices (so Google Home only), using a Google account communicating with Google servers to setup a household.

Comment: in the past it was possible to do the setup from a chrome browser. I wish if it is restriction from google  or just the lack of interest of 3rd parties .

Comment: If using a Chrome browser to do setup, still using a Google product. You can setup [multiple homes for chromecast devices and move devices between homes](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/9155535?hl=en#zippy=%2Cswitch-between-homes). But otherwise Chromecast is using Google's servers to auth/associate devices so no open-source/F-droid equivalent.

Comment: @MorrisonChang  Chrome browser belongs to Google but it is based in open source and multiplatform. Also Chromium, Brave or Opera are based in Chrome and they were able to setup chromecast in the past.

Comment: While other browsers may be able to cast to Chromecast devices, I'll assume it is because Google itself provides SDK for third-party apps/web support: https://developers.google.com/cast. You are asking about `configuration and setup` of chromecast devices which to my knowledge is a Google only service, i.e. out of the box those physical devices only know about Google servers to talk to.